# jquery code validator event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

The problem is that code write for `checkbox` click event.
so if the user first click on `checkbox` then edit the field validator is not work.

i don't want write similar code for `submit` click event because i want disable submit button when the form filed information not valid

here is a jquery:

```
$(".jbcheckboxSignUp").click(function () {
    $(".jbcheckboxSignUp").toggleClass("select");
    var $checkbox = $("#jbCheckBoxSignUp");
    $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
    if ($("button.SignUpButton").attr('disabled') && $('#SignUpForm').validator() && $("#signUpEmail").val()!=""  ) {
        $("button.SignUpButton").removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $("button.SignUpButton").attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: cud u put full code in code runner

Comment: add onsubmit attribute in your form and return false. If validation is ok the only return true.

Comment: @Pirate please read the question with accuracy. i don't want write similar code for submit